# I have an error in my SQL syntax? MySQLi troubles

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So I'm having some mysqli troubles releated to bad syntax and stuff. Here's my code:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['asdf']; 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "<my password>", "blog");
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
$cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['category']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['title']);
$post = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['post']);
$time = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, time());

        if(!empty($_POST)) {
        if(mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO posts (user,catid,title,post,date), VALUES ('$user', '$cat', '$title', '$post', '$time')"))
        echo 'Post successful!';
        else
        echo 'Error: ', mysqli_error($link);
        }
```

All I intend to do is make a simple mysqli post creation script for  a simple little blog I'm making to test and improve my php/sql skills (i'm an extreme noob at this thing) but when I try and create a post using the script i just made it prints this out:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' VALUES ('<Username>', 'Test Post', 'dfgdfsd', 'sdfsd', '1393484072')' at line 1
```

I tried removing the quotes for each variable and doing the sqli query like this instead:

```
if(mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO posts (user,catid,title,post,date), VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", $user, $cat, $title, $post, $time))
```

but that either didn't change anything or threw up a random error about "mysqli expecting most 2 parameters" or something like that. I really don't know where I'm going wrong-- help would be strongly appreciated as I can't find anything on google or over here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma after the column names.  Your query should be something like:

```
"INSERT INTO posts (user,catid,title,post,date) VALUES ('$user', '$cat', '$title', '$post', '$time')"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `,` in your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO posts (user,catid,title,post,date) VALUES ('$user', '$cat', '$title', '$post', '$time')
```

Also, if `catid` is not string datatype (e.g. VARCHAR, TEXT, etc), no need single quote.

Comment: Thanks for making me look stupid :P I should've looked harder... then again, I can't really be entirely at fault considering my completely broken vision and lack of glasses!

Answer (score 0):

You have extra `,` in your query:
try this:

```
if(mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO posts (user,catid,title,post,date) 
 VALUES ('$user', '$cat', '$title', '$post', '$time')")
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Removed `,` before `VALUES` and wrapped **backticks** for the `date` column (reserved word)

```
INSERT INTO posts (user,catid,title,post,`date`) VALUES
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO posts (user,catid,title,post,date), VALUES
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your columns names may be a keyword to mysql.
You should use this :

```
"INSERT INTO posts (`user`,`catid`,`title`,`post`,`date`) VALUES ('$user', '$cat', '$title', '$post', '$time')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try second block in this way,

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {

   /* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
   if (!($stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO posts(user,catid,title,post,date), VALUES (?, ?, ? , ? , ?)"))) {
       echo "Prepare failed: (" . $link->errno . ") " . $link->error;
   }

   /* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
   if (!$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $user, $cat, $title, $post, $time) ) {
      echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
   }

   if (!$stmt->execute()) {
      echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
   }
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php  a better and secure way as mentioned in documentation